Jmeter with Websocket
I am working on JMeter with websocket plugin, when I am using a single user login I can keep the websocket connection 1 day but when I'm trying to connect multiple different logins using csv file my test is failing
I was trying connect to websocket with different users for performance testing but it failed


Try checking the credentials, it might be the case you're either reading or using them incorrectly, use i.e. Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination to see the credentials from the CSV file.
It might be the case your WebSocket server gets overloaded and cannot handle that many users, try starting with 1 virtual user and increasing the load gradually to see what is the maximum supported number and when/why the test starts failing


i have used 1 user it connected websocket and continued the test for 1 day and passed but the problem is when im using 2 credentials , when i am using two different credentials its unable to login to websocket but if i use them manually instead of csv file the test passes for both credentials

Then it looks like your CSV Data Set Config setup is wrong or you're using variables incorrectly. See JMeter Parameterization: The Complete Guide article for some examples and/or share your script and first 2-3 lines of the CSV data so we could take a look and see what's incorrect.
